# Check cookie and redirect user with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site that has a log in page for english and one for french. I am checking for a cookie on page load and if it does not exist redirects user to the english log in page. Is there a way to conditionally check if the user is trying to access a french page to redirect them to the french log in page? Right now I have the logic setup but it creates a bad loop and does not work? is this even possible with jquery?

jQuery:

```
function checkCookie() {
    var current_url = window.location.pathname;
    var logInCookie = _siteNS.Utils.readCookie('x-access');
   
    if (!logInCookie && current_url != '/landing.html') {
      window.location.replace('/landing.html');

    } else if (!logInCookie && current_url != '/landing-fr.html') {
      window.location.replace('/landing-fr.html');
    }
    console.log('cookie', logInCookie);
  }
```

Comment: probably save culture cookie and based on that decide which page to redirect unless you have a way to say which language user should see.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is saying that (assuming there is no `x-access` cookie), if we are not at `/landing.html`, go there. (One second, heading over...) and if you are not at `/landing-fr.html` (No I am NOT! You just sent me to `/landing.html`!) then go *there*... (Ok, fine, I'll go. But I was there already and you sent me away...)

Can you see the loop you are making?

Remember, every time a redirect happens, your code executes in the new page, having no recollection of ever having run before...

Comment: Yes I understand the logic and why it is creating the loop, just a bit stuck on how to execute something like this. I appreciate the info though, thank you :)

Comment: It seemed the OP was confused about this issue. My response was why this issue was happening. Obviously, what the OP is asking is _possible_. It seemed explaining the issue out loud would lead OP to right direction...

Comment: @hendy0817, you asked if you could "conditionally check if the user is trying to access a french page to redirect them to the french log in page?". Your logic tests if the user is _not_ at a given page and then sends them there. This will necessarily send them in a loop since there are 2 such conditional statements. If you have some way of divining which page the user wishes to visit, please add details to your question.

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky the only difference between the english and french pages is the french have the "-fr.html". Just have never done anything like this before so I am trying to get some help with it. I am wondering if I can add an indexOf check and check if the url string contains "fr" and then redirect them to the french login page.

Comment: @hendy0817 I don't understand. You are checking to see if they are at `-fr`. If they are NOT, you are sending them there. What I am missing is, how are you going to figure out if they meant to be there if they aren't there now? Say someone goes to the NON -`-fr` page. They may want to be on the `fr` page, they may not. In what scenario do you know that a user wants `fr` yet user is not requesting the correct page?

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky, I think I see what you are saying. Well they would know they want to be at an '-fr' page if given the direct link form the client. I basically need an edge case check if the user goes to landing-fr.html then the redirect to the landing.html will not fire and allow the user to be on the landing-fr.html without cookie existing.

Comment: What is the contents  of the cookie and how does it affect which page to send the user to?